# Explicit defaulted default constructor and aggregates

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14, default-constructor

How to explain the difference, when I compile `#if 0` and `#if 1` versions of the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>

struct A
{ 
    explicit A() = default; // explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed for aggregates (since C++11)
#if 1
private :
#endif
    int i;
};

int
main()
{
    A a = {};
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

- for `#if 0` all is fine, compilation successful.
- for `#if 1` compilation failed with error message:

  > error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization

What is the difference for expression `A a = {};` depending on whether `A` is aggreagate or not?

Comment: I think you answered it yourself.
When you receive the error A is not an aggregate struct.
So you can't initialize it using an initialization list.

Comment: @Jonathan My own understanding (dumb "it depends on aggregateness") is not quite clear. I want to hear exact explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TL;DR: Clang and GCC are wrong in rejecting your code. [**CWG 1630**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1518)´s resolution made default-initialization well-formed regardless of the chosen default constructor being `explicit` or not.

---

In the variation of your code in which `i` is `private`, `A` is not an aggregate, as these cannot have private members. As long as `i` is `public`, however, `A` is an aggregate<sup>1</sup>, and no constructor is invoked since aggregate initialization is performed (see blue box), so your constructor being `explicit` is irrelevant.

[image]

However, as soon as you introduce the private member, you necessitate value-initialization as per the red box. Hence [dcl.init]/(8.2) applies:

[image]

[dcl.init]/(7.1) defines default-initialization for this case:

[image]

And §13.3.1.3 gives

> For […] default-initialization, the candidate
>   functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being
>   initialized.

At no point is the original context - copy- or direct-initialization - considered. (§13.3.1.7 doesn't apply either.) In fact, this is intended; see [**CWG #1518**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1518):

> This issue is resolved by the resolution of [issue 1630](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1630): **default initialization now uses 13.3.1.3 [over.match.ctor], which now permits explicit constructors for default-initialization.**

Clang and GCC (and VC++) haven't implemented the corresponding DR yet and are thus incorrect in rejecting the code in C++14 mode.

---

<sup>1)</sup>
 Your class has a user-declared constructor, but it isn't user-*provided*, i.e. not impeding your class from being an aggregate. Recall the definition in  [dcl.init.aggr]/1:

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

Comment: Isn't [CWG 1518](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1518) relevant to this case?

Comment: @bogdan Wait, so was my initial conclusion correct?

Comment: I'd say so, but I'm not 100% sure myself :-).

Comment: @bogdan Anyway, thanks a lot for that DR. I completely missed looking those up. Will now adjust my answer.

Comment: @bogdan So what exactly does "this section" mean? How is 13.3.1 more of a "section" than 13.3.1.7? Or is it just me, and it's unambiguous in context?

Comment: 13.3.1 is, obviously, 13.3.1.7's *innermost enclosing* section... sorry, couldn't resist :-). Every time I looked at it, I read it as "this section" == 13.3.1.7. I don't think it would make much sense for it to refer to 13.3.1. After all, that's the entire "candidate functions" section - what other section could 8.5.4 refer to? If it were 13.3.1, mentioning it would be redundant. In short, I agree with the current version of your excellent answer.

Comment: Another confusing thing is that the same paragraph contains *If the initializer list has no elements and T has a default constructor [...]*. I think that's just a leftover from C++11, when the list in 8.5.4 was quite different. As it stands now, I don't see how you could ever get to 13.3.1.7 with an empty initializer list and a default constructor. I'd say that sentence should be removed.

Comment: @bogdan That is *exactly* why I rectified my answer! That paragraph is bogus and should be removed; Should I open the DR?

Comment: Yeah, I say go for it.

Comment: ... Aaand now it appears they're changing their minds (again). Look at the latest notes for [CWG 1518](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1518). I think we'll have to wait a bit longer for a final answer.